# Исправил баг на отдельной ветке и слил в devel. Как добавить изменения в отстающую ветку, над которой работаю?

Tags: git, git-flow

Имеются 2 долгоживущие ветки: `devel` и `master`.

Сначала я ответвился от `devel` в `feature-a` и начал работу над новой фичей, с целью слить ее позже в `devel` (а оттуда уже и в `master`).

В процессе работы обнаружил баг в ранее написанном коде. Ответвился в `bug-#1`, исправил баг, закоммитил, слил изменения в `devel` и ветку `bug-#1` удалил.

Далее переключился обратно на `feature-a`. Но проблема в том, что там еще нет тех изменений, которые пофиксили баг.

Собственно, вопрос: как правильнее поступить?

1. Стоит ли завершить работу над фичей, после чего слить ее в `devel` (и решить конфликты, если будут)?
2. Слить ветку `devel` в `feature-a`, закончить работу над фичей и слить все обратно в `devel`?
3. Или, может быть, есть какие-то более правильные варианты?

Кстати, первый вариант мне кажется совсем неправильным, ведь теоретически может быть такая ситуация, что тот баг, который я уже как бы решил, но в `feature-a` еще не видно, что я его решил, не даст мне завершить работу над фичей.

В общем, прошу совета.

Comment: Есть еще вариант с пересадкой климата с фиксом cherry-pick -ом.  Но как правильнее - решать лично вам. Это от вашего процесса зависит, а не от факта использования гита. Хотя лично мне кажется странным факт мержа фичи в девел без предварительного мержа девела в фичу - конфликты мержа не обязательно проявляются в виде конфликтов гита.

Comment: `git checkout feature; git rebase devel` Правда это зависит являются ли изменения, которые вы уже сделали в `feature` **опубликованными** или нет.

Comment: @PashaPash мерджа фичи в девел еще не было. Он должен быть, когда работа над фичей будет завершена. А зачем мне предварительно девел в фичу сливать? Или вы как раз на мой вопрос отвечаете - чтобы слить в фичу багфикс?

Comment: @0andriy "опубликованными" - это относится к push'ам и прочим операциям с удаленным репозиторием?

Comment: @smellyshovel девел в фичу над сливать (регулярно, хотя бы через rebase через) потому, что иначе вы можете получить логические конфликты на мерже, которые не проявятся как конфликты в файле. Грубо говоря, окончательный мерж фичи в девел пройдет, но вылезет регрессия на чем-то, что поменялось и в девел, и в фиче, но не пересеклось по строчкам.

Comment: @smellyshovel т.е. вы должны делать (2), или через мерж, или через rebase. причем даже в том случае, если ситуации с багом вообще не было.

Comment: @PashaPash но, насколько я понял, вышесказанное справедливо только в тех случаях, когда параллельно работа ведется на нескольких ветках, отделившихся от devel, так?

Comment: Критерии опубликованности определяете вы сами. Я тут ничего не могу сказать.